# 2 div's are not aligning up in height with eachother

Tags: html, css

I have a div with line-numbers next to my `textarea` and basically I can't seem to align them together...

I tried using the `top: 0;` and `bottom: 0;` attributes but they just make it go to the top of my page etc...

Here's the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/77ep92u6/

Any help is appreciated! Thanks

Comment: You should probably remove the javascript tag.

Comment: remove top and bottom from .line-numbers

Comment: If I remove top and bottom, then the div's are still not of equal height

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ashuslove/77ep92u6/2/ see this

Answer (score 0):

Just remembered that CSS has a min-height attribute!

I just set the min-height of both the elements to the same value!

Thank you for all the help!

Comment: If the text area becomes larger than the line-number div this might cause some problems though, will it not?

Answer (score 0):

Use a wrapper around the text element and the div that has a `position: relative`. An element that has a relative position snaps any absolute child elements to itself rather than the document.

```
<div class="area-wrapper">
    <div class="line-numbers">
        <span>1</span>
    </div>
    <textarea class="editor" id="editor"></textarea>
 </div>


.area-wrapper {
    position: relative;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/77ep92u6/1/